# move image while still impacting text

Tags: html, css

I want to move a clickable image to the right of my text. like this:
[image]

i used `position: absolute;` but when i change the size of the page it doesn't impact the size and just overlaps like this:
[image: half picture]

So i thought i change the position to relative but now the text doesn't move up.
[image: position relative]

what am i supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

That's not really meant for that kind of thing.
If you still want to use "position: absolute;", then you would have to create a placeholder. Without a placeholder or free space, there will be visible overlaps.

Position:absolute is often used for menu bars. Then the following content has for example a "margin-top" which takes the height of the menu bar into account.

Normally: You have to make div boxes that can adapt to the size. There are many solutions for a flexible width of the content.

Alternatively, 2 versions or more, for each screen size or device (desktop, tablet, mobile, and everything in between).